# My ActionBar icon isn't clickable

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having some issues with this icon, the thing is that I can do an `onLongPress` then it shows a toast with the text of this item.

My menu "new_offer_menu.xml"

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/newOffer"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:title="@string/nueva_lista"
        android:alphabeticShortcut="r"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

This icon isn't in all of my fragments, but when I go to the correct fragment (where it has to be shown), when I click it doesn't do nothing. In my ListaProductosFragment.java I have :

```
    package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListaProductosFragment extends ListFragment {
    private List<ListViewItem> mItems;        // ListView items list
    private Menu optionsMenu;
    public ListaProductosFragment(){}


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);



        // initialize the items list
        mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
        Resources resources = getResources();

        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tomate_oferta), getString(R.string.aim), getString(R.string.aim_precio), getString(R.string.aim_descuento), getString(R.string.aim_data)));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.levadura_oferta), getString(R.string.youtube), getString(R.string.youtube_precio), getString(R.string.youtube_descuento), getString(R.string.youtube_data)));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.sopa_oferta), getString(R.string.bebo), getString(R.string.bebo_precio), getString(R.string.bebo_descuento), getString(R.string.aim_data)));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.zumo_oferta), getString(R.string.pew), getString(R.string.pew_precio), getString(R.string.pew_descuento), getString(R.string.aim_data)));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tomate_oferta), getString(R.string.aim), getString(R.string.aim_precio), getString(R.string.aim_descuento), getString(R.string.aim_data)));
        // initialize and set the list adapter
        setListAdapter(new ListViewDemoAdapterListaProductos(getActivity(), mItems));
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // remove the dividers from the ListView of the ListFragment
        getListView().setDivider(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // retrieve theListView item
        ListViewItem item = mItems.get(position);

        // do something
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.new_offer_menu,menu );

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar actions click


        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.newOffer:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TipusNouProducte.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
}
```

I've created a toast to see if the problem is the Intent but it doesn't appears anyways, it only do something when I do a LongPress on this item.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` somewhere in the Fragment? It's strange that it shows up and it's not clickable though

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I'm probably mistaken but why does `onOptionsItemSelected` always return `true`? In examples http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html this method returns boolean only from on switch operator

Comment: Edited, and it still not working..

Comment: Post your entire ListaProductosFragment.java and new_offer_menu.xml.

Comment: I've cleanned the project and it only shows the toast...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should change

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/newOffer"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    android:title="@string/nueva_lista"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="r"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

to

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:yourAppName="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">   <--
<item android:id="@+id/newOffer"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    android:title="@string/nueva_lista"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="r"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
--> yourAppName:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

The LongPress behavior, if I'm not mistaken, is a regular behaviour where the system explains to the user the meaning of the menuItem, getting the string from the title tag

```
android:title="@string/nueva_lista"
```

You are not managing it directly, it's Android itself that can manage it, giving you the wrong feeling.

Comment: What do you mean with yourAppName?

Comment: generally it's just a name for your namespace. doesn't even have to be something existing in your project or whatever. may be  xmlns:foo, just like xmlns:bar or xmlns:cookie  as what i know. as long as you then use the same value in your "###:showAsAction"

Comment: Error:(3) No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'info.androidhive.slidingmenu', I don't know how to do that..

Comment: have you added appcompat-v7 support library to your project?

Comment: Read the edit, now appears the toast whenever I click, but It doesn't transact to my other fragment.

Comment: @JoanColmenero FrancescoC has answered you question and you said it has worked. This is now the correct answer.

Comment: I don't see where you call any fragment from your code. The only thing you do after the Toast, is to start a new activity. Maybe you mixed up code between fragment and activity ideas? Either way, if the toast pops up as you say, it means the MenuItem now works